# Load a report on load without selecting parameter

Tags: reporting-services

i have SSRS report which contains two parameters. I want to display the report with some default values from parameters on page load. 
Is there a way to do this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Set a Default Value for the parameter when you create the report:

[image]

You can also set a parameter default through Report Manager after the report has been deployed:

[image]